# Can't set margins with var: JavaScript, CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not very good at programming mobile web layouts and so on.

I've written this:

HTML:

```
<div id="title">...</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#title").css("margin-left", "7%");
$("#title").css("margin-right", "7%");

var i = screen.width * 0.018 + "px";          // It would be 24.588 at resolution of 1366
$("#title").css("margin-top", i);                // And i wanted to use 24.588px here 
$("#title").css("margin-bottom", i);         // and here.
```

And Chrome displays the div margins on the left and right side but doesn't render top and bottom MARGINS...

Comment: `Chrome displays the div margins on the left and right side but doesn't render top and bottom`. Impossible even for left and right margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your `margin_*` properties shouldn't be separated by underscores, but by a `-` dash, like this:

```
$("#title").css("margin-left", "7%");
$("#title").css("margin-right", "7%");

var i = screen.width * 0.018 + "px";
$("#title").css("margin-top", i);
$("#title").css("margin-bottom", i);
```

jQuery's `.css()` method, when used in this form, takes the CSS property name as its first argument and the value to set as its second.

Another, better way of doing it is to pass an object to `.css()`:

```
var margin = screen.width * 0.018 + "px";

$('#title').css({
    marginLeft:   "7%",
    marginRight:  "7%",
    marginTop:    margin,
    marginBottom: margin
});
```

Do note that here you need to use the camel cased versions of the attributes.

Also, why not use a percentage for the top and bottom margins instead of calculating them in JavaScript?

Comment: I was going to edit, to do exactly what you just did! ...I wish I could upvote you twice (for passing an object, instead of using an infinite-chain of `css()`). (Having said I was 'going to,' I then reconsidered and was leaving a comment suggesting that you could do so, it felt a little substantive as an 'edit' from someone else).

Comment: Yes sorry, I wrote it like your examlpe with  margin-top instead of margin_top
The code I posted isn't the original. I think I should use my brain before I write trash:..

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 [No you don't](http://jsbin.com/IKUsOQA/1/edit). jQuery normalises this for you

Comment: What do you mean by that? In the OP, the left and right margins are given a fixed value of 7%, so why use `i`?

Comment: Yes, hah! It's a JS object so of course. I can't believe I missed those out

Answer (score 1):

There don't need any underscores, or dashes, you need to use uppercase letter, like:

```
$("#title").css("marginLeft", "7%");
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might be more simple.**

```
function marge() {
    var sw = $(window).width() * 0.018 + "px";//get margin
    $("#title").css({margin: sw+' 7%'});//set margin tb lr
}
marge();//run initially
$(window).resize(function() { marge(); });//to adjust on resize of the window
```

lines 2 & 3 solve the issue, the rest allows it to run the function again on window resize if needed.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/z2HQL/